# What to do when Docker returns ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Tags: docker, macos

I'm just working through the starter tutorial about Docker.

https://docs.docker.com/get-started/

But hit a wall when I hit chapter 3: https://docs.docker.com/get-started/03_updating_app/

I try to run Dockerfile and get the following response from http://localhost:3000/

> This page isn’t working
>
> localhost didn’t send any data.
>
> ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

I'm running on Monterey. What can I do? Ultimately want to run Windows through Docker.

Comment: Run Windows through Docker? If I'm not horribly mistaken, then Windows doesn't run in a Docker Container ever.

Comment: As you're running Docker on macOS, you should have the Docker desktop app.

Did you check in it if the container did startup? Does the log tell you anything about what could have gone wrong?

Comment: I'll try desktop. What is the best way to run Windows on MacOS? I assumed I could run Docker image.

Comment: Some kind of virtualisation would be my way to go. Take your pick from VMWare, Parallels and VirtualBox (most certainly there a others) and install Windows in a VM.